# Unable to upload app update to app store

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 8.3.3.I have already uploaded the previous version of my app to iTunes connect, but I am facing a weird issue when trying to upload from Xcode as well as application loader.The message said that my provisioning profile is invalid.I unticked "Automatically manage signing" in general tab.Then I am receiving the following issue

Signing certificate is invalid.
Signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: ", serial number "", is not valid for code signing. It may have been revoked or expired.

Please help me solve this.I am attaching the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try Automatic sign in. select your account in drop down that you are using in itunes connect. Than export your build for iOS Distribution and try to upload using application loader because it gives perfect error that you are facing in the upload so you can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete All Provisioning Profile and Clear once then download all ProvisioningProfile again and again clear and remove derived data.
then try with automatically manage signing.